# Android: posting message to HandlerThread makes UI thread unresponsive or gives IllegalStateException

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to make use of `HandlerThread` in android and am ending up with either a situation in which the UI thread is not responding anymore, or a strange `IllegalStateException`. I want to give you a minimal example of my problem.

I have a class `DataManager` which instantiates a worker thread on creation:

```
public class DataManager
{
    private final HandlerThread loaderThread = new HandlerThread( "Worker" );
    private final Producer loader;
```

Inside of this class I have my `Handler` defined:

```
    private static class Producer extends Handler
    {
        public Producer( Looper looper )
        {
            super( looper );
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage( Message msg )
        {
            msg.recycle();
        }
    }
```

The constructor of my `DataManager` runs the worker thread and associates the handler with the thread's looper:

```
    public DataManager()
    {
        loaderThread.start();
        this.loader = new Producer( loaderThread.getLooper() );
    }
```

Before `DataManager` is destroyed, it stops the thread and waits for it to finish. Actually I believe this part is not relevant to my problem, because my `DataManager` instance is definitely alive all the time:

```
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable
    {
        loaderThread.quit();
        loaderThread.join();

        super.finalize();
    }
```

Finally, I have `doSomething` method, which simply posts a message to the worker thread:

```
    public void doSomething()
    {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        loader.sendMessage( msg );
    }
```

Now I'm instantiating the `DataManager` from inside of a custom view on the UI thread. When the view is about to paint itself using `onDraw` it calls `doSomething` on the `DataManager`. The further behavior depends on whether an `AsyncTask` is currently running in background or not:

- If it is running, than the UI thread is becoming unresponsive form this moment on.
- Otherwise, I get an `IllegalStateException`, thrown from within a subroutine of `Looper.loop` of the UI thread, saying:

> IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.
>   
>   Google gives absolutely no results for this message. I've been reading documentation and searching for similar problems for a few hours now and still have no idea what I might be doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it. Obsiously the situation about recycling messages is [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg67953.html):

> If you send it to a handler, the handler/looper will recycle it for you.

So one **must not** recycle the message within `handleMessage`.