# Crash with animations on top of camera preview

Tags: android, animation, android-camera2

I am getting crash when animating views with camera preview.

Trace is following:

> D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x702565a400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x701d23cc60
>
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.
>          at android.os.MessageQueue.removeSyncBarrier(MessageQueue.java:512)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1248)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6338)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

I have implemented camera preview using Googles example and on top of the preview there is "auto-focus" oval which is animated visible/hidden using `animate()`method and alpha.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Thread/Handler Error IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization barrier token has not been posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554809/android-thread-handler-error-illegalstateexception-the-specified-message-queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I wasn't forcing the thread to main when getting callback from the camera preview.

```
 private Handler mAutoFocusHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Using this `Handler` to post `Runnable` where to animate the auto focus fixes the issue.

**NOTE:** Make sure to check that you are animating your own views on UI thread because `View.animate()` seemed to work when started from the camera background thread, but occasionally crashed the app.